# Cant execute simple query to Alfresco with CMIS WORKBENCH

Tags: alfresco, cmis, cmis-workbench

I am trying to execute this simple query to Alfresco with CMIS WORKBENCH and I am getting some errors:

```
SELECT * FROM cmis:document
```

When I check the log, there is a lot of exceptions. These are (to me) the relevants:

> The Web Script /alfresco/service/cmis/queries has responded with a status of 500 - Internal Error.
>
> Message:   09180065 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 09185424 Failed to execute script 'classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/cmis/queries.post.cmisquery.js': 09185423
>
> Exception:    java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredException - NotAfter:
>   Fri Aug 17 07:34:11 VET 2012
>   Exception:    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException - timestamp
>   check failed
>   Exception:    org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.lucene.LuceneQueryParserException
>   - 09185423 Exception: org.alfresco.scripts.ScriptException - 09185424 Failed to execute script
>   'classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/cmis/queries.post.cmisquery.js':
>   Exception:    org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptException
>   - 09180065 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 09185424 Failed to execute script
>   'classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/cmis/queries.post.cmisquery.js':
>   09185423

Does anybody knows what this exceptions means? Thanks for any help!

Comment: have you checked if you're using SSL to connect to Alfresco, and if the certificates are all right?

Comment: That error means that your certificate has expired. Are you using SSL? And are you perhaps using an old version of Alfresco with an expired certificate built in?

Comment: I was not using SSL. The errors went away just by updating to 4.2 version. (I forgot to mention that I was with 4.0), Thanks!

Comment: Please create an answer and explain about the version, then accept it yourself. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an offical [post](https://forums.alfresco.com/en/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=45940) from the Alfresco Forum, which is related to this problem.

It says that the default SSL certificate, which was delivered with your Alfresco will expire on the 17th August 2012 - that matches the exception in the log file:

```
Exception: java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredException - NotAfter: Fri Aug 17 07:34:11 VET 2012
```

The post also links to an [article](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Alfresco_And_SOLR#Generating_new_SSL_certificates) in the Alfresco Wiki, where the generation of new SSL certificates for SOLR (which handles the CMIS queries) is explained.

This error is caused by Alfresco and should not be CMIS-related.

**Additional information**

[Blog post](http://blogs.alfresco.com/wp/wabson/2012/08/31/creating-self-signed-ssl-certificates-for-solr/) about creating self-signed certificates for SOLR.

Comment: Thanks, It makes sense, I will try to generate a new certificate and let's see what happens, Regards!